# Opening a new image onclick in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to make a page containing multiple images. What I want is: when i click the displayed image it should open another image with its description.I have images stored in local library. I tried *href* in *html tag* but it won't take local paths. Is there any way in which it can be achieved

I'd like to ask about:

```
<a href="./Docs/slider images/010.png">
<img src={require('./Docs/spark.png')}/>
</a>
```

here i am not able to open *'010.png'* on clicking *'spark.png'*

Comment: Can you put the images where the web server has access to it? Like in an `assets/images` directory or something?

Comment: Not clear,do you have any sample code or site

Comment: I'm making a sample gallery app using react. The images are stored in my local pictures directory. Previously i made same page using html and it worked fine, now in react having trouble.

Comment: What do you mean by "open another image with its description"? What do you mean by _open_, a modal, a new window?

Comment: <div>
              <a href="./Docs/slider images/010.png" >
                <img src={require('./Docs/head.png')} alt=""/>
                  <h2>Engine Cross Head</h2>
              </a>
            </div>

Comment: since <img> is enclosed in <a href=...> tag so on clicking the <img>it should invoke <a href=...>

Comment: What _does_ happen when you click the `<a>`?

Comment: The screen simply flashes and back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is the `space` in the location. Try the following!

```
const img = require('./Docs/slider-images/010.png')

const srcImg = require('./Docs/spark.png')

<a href={img}>
  <img src={srcImg}/>
</a>
```